# JMS and Weblogic Clustering

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, weblogic-10.x, cluster-computing

Weblogic application servers that I am using are clustered. I have a created a JMS queue and it has a JNDI name. When a consumer looks up the jndi name and publishes the event on a queue , would it be published in the queue created in both the app servers? The same MDB will be running on both the servers - which one will get the message posted on to the queue? In case I need to delete the message put on the queue , should I iterate through all the nodes and delete the message?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the JMS module XML configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Using a queue means the message is *guaranteed* to be consumed exactly *once*. Meaning, that the message will be delivered to both nodes, but it will only be processed *once* globally by one of the nodes. WebLogic handles the synchronization and coordination between nodes in your cluster to simultaneously guarantee the delivery, but assure that it is processed exactly once globally.

This is contrast to a topic, where each subscriber gets a copy of the message. Each message will be processed once by each subscriber.

You don't need to iterate through the nodes to delete the message... just grab a jndi reference to the queue and delete the message before any consumer consumes it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what type of queue you're creating within Weblogic for this. For a clustered environment it's better to use a DistributedQueue, rather than a standard Queue. I believe it allows Weblogic to better handle how to deal with messages on the queue when one of the nodes in the cluster goes down. There is also the option to view the contents of a queue and delete messages from the Weblogic Admin Console.